# IGBT emitter collector spike overshoot

Tags: inverter, igbt, spike, overshoot

I am building a step up transformer for an output of 100 kV, 50 mA, at 50 kHz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA5ewm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For that I have planned to use a half bridge circuit with a ferrite transformer. However to test the circuit I am putting 30 V DC across a half bridge input. I am using a TLP350 as a Gate driver. I am using 10 Ω resistor as a *gate turn on* resistance, and a 1N5822 as a *turn off* diode for gate driver.

[image: Lower side IGBT gate voltage]

This is my lower side IGBT gate voltage, the probe directly connected at IGBT legs. 15 V. The probe is in 10X mode...

[image: Half bridge output]

This is my half bridge output, load is a 60 Watt 12 Volt car headlight.

[image: Voltage spike/overshoot at the leg of lower side IGBT]

**This is my issue, a voltage spike/overshoot at the leg of lower side IGBT. Probe is connected in emitter and collector pin. Collector pin referenced to emitter**. This waveform taken without the snubber circuits.

My question is how I can reduce the spike at the IGBT's collector emitter pin?

[image: Test setup]

This is my test setup for now. I have a **2 µf, 2 kV snubber** cap close to half bridge IGBTs. **10 kΩ** resistor connected in gate and emitter at both IGBT to reduce accidental turn on. I am using **IHW40N65R5** IGBT with **DSEI60-12A** diode with each IGBT.

[image: Lower side IGBT collector emitter voltage with snubber]

After I put the snubber circuit my lower side IGBT collector emitter voltage look like this, spike reduced but little ringing happening now... Is that ok? Can I power up my circuit up to high voltage DC? Like 300 Volt DC?

Comment: Show your circuit diagram.

Comment: No need to SHOUT in the title of your question. And **no circuit** means **no answer**. What is electronics about? Circuits. It eludes me why so many of you ask a question but don't include the **circuit**. *But the circuit is so common* sure but include it anyway. And is it **EXACTLY** as that "common circuit"? *Yes, but I changed...* So it is not exactly the same then. Details matter, that's why EEs use **circuit diagrams**.

Comment: This kind of photo, with no schematic, makes me want to sneak up behind the poster, and clap once.

Comment: Bad layout and bad probing. Improve both and measure again.

Comment: @winny  Bad Probing means You want me to shorten the Ground Loop in probe ??  And for the layout i still didn't make the pcb, Shoud i need to make pcb before testing ???

Comment: Correct. A pigtail is perferred. Yes, a real PCB or accept that you are probably snubbing away a layout related issue in this (I presume) prototype stage.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, OP is a newcomer, so make them welcome. Please don't accuse them of shouting then do far worse. Cut the bold-shouting and the patronising tones, they drag the site's reputation right down. EEs treat anybody else - anybody - professionally and well, so become one of us who leads by example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting the inductance solved the issue.